# Splitting JSON response and using data for chart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am using jQuery/AJAX to receive a response from my PHP backend in JSON in the following format:

```
{"result":[["Cellphone","900"],["Medical","900"],["Repair and Maintenance","3700"],["Travel","867.2"]],"errors":false}
```

This is how I am generating the JSON from the PHP backend:

```
    $addresult = "
        SELECT category,SUM(receiptamount)  
        FROM scans              
        GROUP BY category;          
    ";

     if( $result = $mysqli->query($addresult) ) {
        // collect results
        while($row = $result->fetch_all())
        {
            // assign to new array
            // make returnResult an array for multiple results
            $returnResult = $row;
        }
    }

...
echo json_encode(['result' => $returnResult, 'errors' => $errors]);
```

This is my jQuery/AJAX `success` function:

```
success: function(response) {
if(!response.errors && response.result) {

    var str = (response.result[1]).toString();
    var str_array = str.split(',');
    for(var i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++) {
       str_array[i] = str_array[i].replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");
       //alert(str_array[i]);
    }
    var chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: document.getElementById('chart'),
        data: {
            columns: [
                ['Travel', 30],
                ['Accommodation', 130],
                ['Cellphone', 130],
                ['Donation', 130],
                ['Gift', 130],
                ['Medical', 130],
                ['Repair and Maintenance', 130],
                ['Other Expense', 130]
            ],
            type: 'bar'
        },
        bar: {
            width: {
                ratio: 0.5 // this makes bar width 50% of length between ticks
            }
        }
    });

} else {
    myApp.alert('Something went wrong', 'Oops!');
}
}
```

I want to then generate the chart column names and the corresponding amounts from this data but I have no idea how to.

Comment: FYI, no loop needed just `$returnResult = $result->fetch_all();`

Comment: Thank you! I was re-using some old code and forgot to take out the loop.

Comment: can you elaborate on the last part "and the correspoding amounts"? What do you mean? Should the amounts be part of the column header name?

Comment: Looks like you're taking an array, converting it to a string, and then converting it back into an array by `.split`ing the string??

Comment: @Poku. For example, `["Cellphone","900"]` in this I want a column in the chart to have the name "Cellphone" and the value that needs to be charted "900"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can simply change this:

```
data: {
    columns: [
        ['Travel', 30],
        ['Accommodation', 130],
        ['Cellphone', 130],
        ['Donation', 130],
        ['Gift', 130],
        ['Medical', 130],
        ['Repair and Maintenance', 130],
        ['Other Expense', 130]
    ],
    type: 'bar'
},
```

to this:

```
data: {
    columns: response.result,
    type: 'bar'
},
```

Answer (score 1):

So based on your posted json data you can extract the columns like this:

```
var json = { 
result : [
    ["Cellphone",900],["Medical",900],["Repair and Maintenance",3700],["Travel",867.2]
],
errors:false
}

var chartColumns= json.result.map(x => x[0] + " " + x[1]);
console.dir(columns);
```

and then set the charts columns source to the chartColumns

```
var chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: document.getElementById('chart'),
        data: {
            columns: chartColumns,
            type: 'bar'
        },
        bar: {
            width: {
                ratio: 0.5 // this makes bar width 50% of length between ticks
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. When I `alert(chartColumns)` I only see the column names, but not the numbers. Any idea why?

Comment: I changed the code so it also contains the amount. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much Poku, I really appreciate the help :)